# What should I insert between <tag-class></tag-class> tags in .tld file?

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

1. I've got a problem. I don't know what should I put between tags `<tag-class></tag-class>`. I'm trying to do a simple webapp and I'd like to use (in JSP pages) my own tag.
2. And the second thing is that uri tags don't work (I think it can be somehow related to `<tag-class>` tags). I program in IntelliJ IDEA and it highlights me this bug (about uri tags).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.2</tlib-version>
    <short-name>RandomTags</short-name>
    <function>
        <name>test</name>
        <function-class>myPackage.Person</function-class>
        <function-signature>int methodForTLDTesting()</function-signature>
    </function>
    <uri>randomThings</uri>
    <tag>
        <description>description</description>
        <name>name</name>
        <tag-class></tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

Comment: You can always open up the schema (XSD) and check what is required. In this case it's "The tag handler class implementing javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.JspTag" (fully qualified class name). The question is do you actually have a tag implemented?

Comment: Thank You for your answer Dennis. I found the solution studying my book. But I'd like to ask You about the shcema XSD. What is it? I've heared about it for the first time. Maybe You can give me any link where I can read about it.

Comment: And I recommend book: Head First Servlets & jsp, for evaeryone who starts programming in Java EE.

Comment: A good resource for that is http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp

Comment: Thank You again. All the best